# multiautocompletetextview dropdown not displaying

Tags: android

I'm creating my own keyboard and placing each letter typed into the MultiAutoCompleteTextView using mMultiAuto.setText.  I've followed all the tutorials with creating

```
mMultiAuto = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView)findViewById( R.id.multiautotextview );
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
    mMultiAuto.setAdapter(adapter);  
    mMultiAuto.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());
```

The problem is when I type a letter into the textview, the dropdownlist doesn't show.  can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

Replace your code with following

```
mMultiAuto = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView)findViewById( R.id.multiautotextview );
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
        mMultiAuto.setAdapter(adapter);  

                            mMultiAuto.setThreshold(1);

                            mMultiAuto.setAdapter(soAdapter);

                            mMultiAuto.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                                @Override
                                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
                                {
                                    mMultiAuto.showDropDown();
                                    return false;
                                }
                            });
```